# emacs elisp why won't a variable work here?

Tags: emacs

Why does the following not work when defining a org-capture-template:

```
(add-to-list 'org-capture-templates
         '("1" "Ideas"  entry
           (file (concat note-dir "/ideas.org"))
           "* IDEA %?" :empty-lines 1))
```

When I evaluate the concat sexp it as the value that I require. So why does "file" not like it?
Also, what is "file" how can I find out what it is, describe-function doesn't work so presumably not a function.
Thanks

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate. Look for `backquote`.

Comment: Yes thanks, that solves it. Lot's to learn.